# Does anyone know of an iPaper alternative?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, documentviewer, ipaper

We would like to display office documents in the browser (DOC, PPT, XLS and PDFs). The iPaper API from Scribd is perfect but ideally it would be installed on our server. Open source is a preference but commercial is ok. Looking for an easy, server side, good looking, minimal interface flash frontend viewer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Document Viewer](http://docs.google.com/viewer) in embedded mode. It cannot be installed on your server and your documents will have to be accessible from the web.